# How does resistance work?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, damage-resistance

For instance, the [Cavalier fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Cavalier)'s [Warding Maneuver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#WardingManeuver-687) feature description (XGtE, p. 30) says, in part:

> [...] Roll the die, and add the number rolled to the target’s AC against that attack. If the attack still hits, the target has resistance against the attack’s damage. [...]

What is the resistance? Is it a value you subtract from the damage, and if so what is that value?

Comment: Welcome, Kevin.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how this Q&A site is different from an internet forum.  Also, please take a look at [this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/22566) to understand where all of those down votes came from.  Don't worry, each of us has had to get a feel for how an SE site works a bit differently than most other internet sites.  Please browse the other questions and answers on RPG's that interest you. Again, Welcome! ..  and Happy Gaming.

Answer (score 32):

*Resistance* is a game term which means that a creature takes half damage from a specific source.

From the Player's Handbook (pg. 197)

> If a creature or an object has resistance to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it. If a creature or an object has vulnerability to a damage type, damage of that type is doubled against it.

*Resistance* can come from many sources, including racial traits, class features, monster special traits, and spells. For example, Tieflings have a racial trait that gives them resistance to fire damage.

Also note that you always round damage down, so 15 damage becomes 7, not 8.

> **Round Down**
>   There’s one more general rule you need to know at the outset.  Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater. (Basic Rules, p. 4)

In this case, if the attack hits the target (even after adding the AC from Warding Maneuver) you divide the damage the target would take by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If a character has resistance to something, for example, piercing damage, that damage type is halved against it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  What this site accepts is supported answers.  While I think you are correct, providing support to the answer will improve it.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how SE sites are different from discussion forums.